# What findOne returns when there is no match?

Tags: sequelize.js

My `nodejs` app needs to check if `findOne` find any match.

```
  let o = await Model.findOne({where : {name: 'myname'}});
  if (no match in o ) {
  //do something
  } else {
  //do something else
  };
```

But I did not find any document explaining what `findOne` returns when there is no match. I know it does not return `null` or `undefined`. The return is an object and how I know there is no match.

Comment: check the last part of the this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#the-findone-result-document . This might help you

Comment: What i found was that `null` was the return without match in debug. This is as expected when there is no match found in the table.

Comment: In order to use `await`, you have to create a new Promise object for the fineOne. Otherwase `o` will always be `undefine` which is false;                                                                                                                                                                                                    await new Promise(() => {Model.fineOne({where: {name: 'myname'}})}).then(result => {o = result});

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you go , as per the **[DOC](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html)** and below example , it will **either return the record or null** (for no record found) :

```
// search for attributes
Project.findOne({ where: {title: 'aProject'} }).then(project => {
  // project will be the first entry of the Projects table with the title 'aProject' || null
})
```

---

So in your case , you can do it like :

```
let o = await Model.findOne({where : {name: 'myname'}});
if (o) {
    // Record Found
} else {
    // Not Found
};
```

Comment: Was expecting like 2nd example. Thank you.